# Fluid layout in CSS doesn't keep proportions

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

Im trying to build a fluid layout in CSS with percentages instead of pixels. I want it so that if the user tries to zoom in on the website, all internal proportions should stay the same.

Right now, when I zoom in, the text grows out of the drivs and the layout breaks.

I'm using a wrapper and three columns which has about 30 percent in width each.

Since this is sort of a layout problem, I've posted the entire layout on JSBin. The problem is apparent there as well. When you zoom in, the internal proportions break and the text grows out.

http://jsbin.com/zerewuto/1/

Anyone got any ideas how to fix this?

[image: How it looks when you zoom in]

Comment: It should be mentioned that responsiveness is not **strictly** related to **zooming**.

Comment: this is because you are using a oldest way to build fluid layouts, and asign fixed height to the child divs, instead you can use Flexbox layout model. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Flexbox will work if your fine with the layout breaking in IE 8 and 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In top of your css add:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

This makes the box model calculate paddings and borders **inside** of the box. It's best to use when working with relative measures. (Or always)

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention. The reason the layout breaks is because of margins. At a point they + the percentage becomes more than 100%.

Consider a page that is `100px` wide only. Then each `10px` margin would be equal to `10%`.

Lycka till!

Comment: Totally agree, Bootstrap 3 uses that technique but notes that [IE8 does not fully support box-sizing: border-box; when combined with min-width, max-width, min-height, or max-height. For that reason, as of v3.0.1, we no longer use max-width on .containers.](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support) Fortunately IE8 is on its way out...although still not gone.

Comment: True. We just dropped IE8 at work this year so I'm trying to just forget it ever existed. :D

Comment: I'm not sure that helped. Still not working in the JSBin example. The text in the columns are set to 70% of it's internal space. Yet it breaks out of the divs when I zoom in. Same goes for the title and subtitle. Why is that?

Comment: You've also set height to 95%. Why is that?

Comment: It breaks because of margins.

Comment: So that there's some room between the bottom and the divs. It's not important. I'll remove it. But I don't think it solves the problem.

Comment: The horizontal margins.

Comment: Right I'll try again! Tack förresten!

Comment: I suggest you study this http://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/ and adapt it to your needs. Also don't use height for spacing, use padding or margin.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add `word-break: break-all` to your CSS.

I would like to warn you that Liquid / Fluid layouts do not prescribe the use of percentage values for everything as this can easily cause display problems like this.

Use pixel values and percentage values reasonably to achieve a robust liquid design.